# How to use Yahoo REST Api in C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, key, yahoo

I'm just trying to make an yahoo boot that send to registered user of my application an instant message. I've spent some hours searching the web on how to do it but yahoo developer documentation sucks.First of all I don't know what servers I should use for authorization, log in, and messaging. I have a consumer key and I've tried to follow [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html) steps but nothing works.

Any advice/suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation looks to be very good, I think the issue here is that your knowledge of how REST API's work in general is a bit lacking.

**Let's talk about diagram #2: Get a request token using:** `get_request_token`.

`get_request_token` is part of an HTTP endpoint, and in their diagram they want you to pass in a handful of parameters to validate your request.

- oauth_consumer_key
- oauth_nonce
- oauth_signature_method
- etc

*(If you need more clarification of any step you can find it in the tree view on the left hand side of the page)*

**The request URL:**

`https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token`.

Now at this point you can either use the HTTP `GET` or `POST` verb. If you decide to use `GET` you will need to include those above parameters as a query string.

`?oath_consumer_key=myConsumerKey&oauth_nonce=oathNonce` etc

I will leave it to you to write the associated C# code. You'll want to start off with the `HttpWebRequest.Create()` method

Comment: I guess [documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/Messenger-IM-SDK/not-getting-response-for-https-api-login-yahoo-com-oauth-v2-get-request-token/1310023528000-09714556-4cd3-38c5-b799-d29e8d5f9bcb) is old. :(